# If the limit of the integral exists, does the limit of the integral of the absolute values also exist?

Tags: real-analysis

Hi everyone: Let $ B $ be an open ball in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $, $ n\geq2 $, and let $ (f_{n}) $ be a sequence of continuous (or even differentiable) functions such that 
$$ \int_{B}f_{n}(x)dx =-1$$ for all natural number $ n. $ Here is my question: can we conclude that 
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}\int_{B}\lvert f_{n}(x)\rvert dx $$ exists?

Comment: Open ball ? Am I the only one who don't know what does it mean ?

Comment: @Leth $\{ x\in\Bbb R^n\,:\, \lVert x-c\rVert<r\}$

Comment: WLOG we will work in $\mathbb R^2$ on the unit ball. Construct a sequence of continuous (or smooth, really) functions that take on large values on the left-half of the ball and small values on the right-half, but in a way so that the integral is always $-1$. Then the absolute value of the function gets arbitrarily large as $n \to \infty$, from which it is not too difficult to show that the integral also does (if the functions are chosen correctly)

Comment: @Leth This is a generalization of an open interval, $(b-r,b+r)$, in $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $, $ n\geq2 $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: consider two functions $g_1,\,g_2\in C^\infty_c(B)$ such that $\int_Bg_i(x)\,dx=-1$ and call $$f_n=\begin{cases}g_1&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\g_2&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\end{cases}$$

Then, the sequence $\int_B\lvert f_n(x)\rvert\,dx$ is $$\int_B\lvert g_2(x)\rvert\,dx,\ \int_B\lvert g_1(x)\rvert\,dx,\ \int_B\lvert g_2(x)\rvert\,dx,\ \int_B\lvert g_1(x)\rvert\,dx,\cdots$$

If what you say were true, then the sequence above should be constant, implying that all $f\in C^\infty_c(B)$ such that $\int_Bf(x)\,dx=-1$ have the same integral of the absolute value. Which is clearly false, because, if $K=\operatorname{supp}f\subsetneqq B$, you can pick $0\ne g\in C^\infty_c(B\setminus K)$ with $\int_B g(x)\,dx=0$ and consider $f+g$. Since the supports of $f$ and $g$ are disjoint, $$\lvert f+g\rvert=\lvert f\rvert +\lvert g\rvert$$ and $f+g\in C^\infty_c(B)$.

But $$\begin{cases}\int_B f(x)+g(x)\,dx=-1\\ \int_B \lvert f(x) +g(x)\rvert\,dx=\int_B\lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx+\int_B\lvert g(x)\rvert\,dx>\int_B\lvert f(x)\rvert\,dx\end{cases}$$